# Alternative to Template<T> method when using Kendo with asp.net mvc core gridbuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am converting my project from asp.net mvc to asp.net core 2, and the extension method that allows me to set a custom template based on the row content that I make use of heavily in kendo mvc is missing in kendo core.

In the example below, the commented-out column definition works as expected in the original asp.net mvc project, but not in the asp.net core 2 project.

```
@model List<QuarterViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Quarter")
        .Columns(c =>
        {
          c.Bound(m => m.Title).Title("Quarter");
          //c.Bound(m => m.YearNumber).Title("Quarter").Template(q => Html.ActionLink($"{q.YearNumber}-{q.QuarterNumber}", "Details", new { id = q.QuarterId }));             
        }))
```

Looking at the source, I can see that the grid column builder class returned by the `Title()` call differs between versions of the `kendo.mvc.dll`, but I haven't found any documentation that explains the change or what the alternative to using the `Template()` call is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is lightly indicated at https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/known-issues

> **Known Issues** 
>   This articles summarizes all known issues related to
>   Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core.
>   …
>   **Common Issues** 
>   - Limited set of helpers. Interim releases will add more
>   widgets.
>   - Localization is a work in progress. For a discussion, refer
>   to aspnet/Home/issues/1124.
>   - Deferred() can be invoked only as a last
>   setting.

I don't know of an exhaustive list of differences or un-implemented helpers.

Comment: Thanks for that. Specifics [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/known-issues#grid): Server-side rendering is not supported.